# LLDB make command from script

Tags: lldb, macos-mojave

I created `step-scripted` that print for me the name of function the debugger calls.

Now I want to automate the part that I need to type:
`thread step-scripted -C MyTrace.Trace`

How can I run the above command from a script?

so I will do something like this:

```
script
while True:
    thread step-scripted -C MyTrace.Trace
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, there's no reason that a step plan has to do just one step.  If you want to step forever, then just have the step plan do it - never set the plan to complete, and return false from `should_stop`.  Even more convenient, if you are using a recent lldb, you can pass arguments to your scripted step plan using the `-k <key> -v <value>` arguments.  So you could also have your plan take a "count" input, and step that many times.

Otherwise, the easiest way to do this is to use the Python interface to implement a custom command that automates this step.  SBThreads are the things you step.  If you use the command form that takes an SBExecutionContext, described here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#id6

you can get the thread from `SBExecutionContext.thread` then use `SBThread. StepUsingScriptedThreadPlan` to call your thread plan to do the step.  Once you are in python, writing a loop to do this forever or till some condition, etc. should be easy.  Your command could also take number of times to step, etc.

Note, you can also run commands in the script interpreter using `SBCommandInterpreter.HandleCommand` if that seems easier to you.

Comment: Thanks, now I have a new problem, the program is a GUI program when I set `should_stop` to false and not set `plan ` to complete it continues to print the GUI loop forever and not letting me advanced the program to the wanted point, how can I trace the program calls in a way it's still let me operate the program and later understand the flow?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand.  If you are stepping all the time through the code, then the program you are debugging is going to be interrupted all the time by the debugger, and will likely be pretty hard to interact with.  But all its threads should be alive and running.